# Trying to calculate uptime and email if greater than a number of days

Tags: timestamps, uptime

I need to create a script that will execute daily (`cron` job), calculate the uptime of the system (days only), and if that number is greater than a defined value (e.g. 30), email the system's information (`uname -a`) and the number of days to some address (e.g. `admin@company.com`).

I am getting lost in converting the value of days to something I can perform a calculation on and take action. Started by using the

```
uptime | grep -o "up.*day"
```

command but then got stuck. Using CentOS 7.8.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have `uptime -s`? E.g. uptime in seconds: `echo "$(( $(date +'%s') - $(date -d"$(uptime -s)" +'%s') ))"`. If the value is greater than 3600*24*30, then ...

Answer (score 3):

The documentation `man uptime` offers this snippet

> `-s, --since` - system up since, in `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format

So you can get an absolute date/time from which the counting commenced

```
uptime -s
2020-02-12 12:37:16
```

Subtract that from the current date/time and you'll get days. (It's a little more fiddly as date maths is usually in seconds)

```
# Seconds at boot
secSince=$(date --date "$(uptime -s)" +%s)

# Seconds now
secNow=$(date +%s)

# Difference
secInterval=$((secNow - secSince))

# Convert to days
daysInterval=$((secInterval / (60*60*24)))

echo "$daysInterval day(s) uptime"
```

If there's been a leap second added during the calculated interval the reported day may be off by one within a couple of seconds of your local midnight.