# How can I remove an error from the beginning of my script without setting my variable as null?

Tags: bash, shell-script, macos

I'm running into an issue where my script will only set the integer that I need for the variable `$alive` if I allow the following error to show.
`uptime: /dev/ttys001: No such file or directory`

I've attempted to remove this by adding `&>/dev/null` either behind `uptime` or behind the command in this context below,

```
(( uptime | grep -ohe 'up .*' | sed 's/,//g' | awk '{ print $2 }')&>/dev/null)
```

or

```
( uptime &>/dev/null | grep -ohe 'up .*' | sed 's/,//g' | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

but this causes the following to happen

```
This computer has been awake for  days
```

whereas I need it to set the variable and perform like so

```
This computer has been awake for 32 days
```

This is more of a personal project for me to understand scripting using bash within MacOS so any additional insight is greatly appreciated!

Here is the script in its context. It is intended to be an infinite loop to keep the computer on for remote access at all times and can be stopped by simply terminating the running process.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

alive=$( uptime | grep -ohe 'up .*' | sed 's/,//g' | awk '{ print $2 }')

until [[ $alive -lt 0 ]]; do
  Caffeinate -d -t 2
  sleep 2
  echo "This computer has been awake for $alive days"
done
```

Eventually I'd like to have the computer hit a certain amount of days, then break and restart, automatically login, and launch the process over again to ensure that performance is not hindered by the computer being awake for months on end.

But I haven't had the time to work on that just yet ;)

Comment: Sharing some possible simplifications: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257142/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586750/trying-to-calculate-uptime-and-email-if-greater-than-a-number-of-days

Comment: Be aware that `uptime`'s output will vary. Less than a day will print the hours elapsed, more than that it will print `timenow up x days, ...`.

Comment: Yes that is expected, the use of caffeinate for 2 seconds is for testing purposes. The plan is to caffeinate for a full day at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of `uptime`’s output to its standard error:

```
alive=$( uptime 2>/dev/null | grep -ohe 'up .*' | sed 's/,//g' | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

`&>/dev/null` redirects both standard output and standard error to the bit bucket, so you end up with *no* output to process, and your variable is set to the empty string. `2>/dev/null` only redirects standard error, getting rid of any error message, but preserving the regular output.

Note that `awk` can do everything `grep` and `sed` can; I don’t know the exact output of `uptime` on your system, but on mine the following works:

```
alive=$(uptime 2>/dev/null | awk '/up/ { print $3 }')
```

Comment: Thank you! what does 2> do as opposed to &>? This did solve the problem.

Comment: `2>` redirects standard error, `&>` redirects both standard output and standard error (which is why you were losing the “normal” output from `uptime`).

Comment: An alternative way to do this is `2>&-`, which closes file descriptor 2, instead of sending it to `/dev/null`. However, a few programs don't react well to this.

Comment: @ddawson programs are allowed to expect their standard error to be open when they start; `2>&-` breaks that expectation.

Comment: As he is using sed to get rid of commas, the `uptime 2>/dev/null | awk '/up/ { print $3 }'` will have a trailing comma.

Comment: @annahri only if the third field ends with a comma, which isn’t the case here apparently. (It would be better to search for `day`, I guess.)

Comment: If the uptime is less than a day, it will have a comma. For example, `14:16:38 up  3:57,  0 users,  load average: 0.52, 0.58, 0.59`

Comment: Yes, hence my point about searching for “day”; the script in the question assumes that there’s a number of days in the output.

Comment: @annahri on my system (MacOS) the 4th field states the unit of measurement (mins, hours, days, etc.) and that field is what has the trailing comma.